# Easy Applications of Model Theory

Tags: reference-request, model-theory, applications

The question is inspired by [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7018/model-theoretic-applications-to-algebra-and-number-theoryiwasawa-theory) and [this post on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263961/applications-of-model-theory-to-analysis).

The applications mentioned are usually pretty complicated (except for Ax-Grothendieck, but it seems to be a rare occurrence). Aside from these examples, are there easy "applications of model theory"? For example, can we use Morley's categorecity theorem to determine that a class of structures of interest "outside of model theory" has only unique models in higher cardinalities, where the actual proof of the fact is fairly complicated. I know that this works for $\mathrm{ACF}_0$ for example, but it seems this can be established with the same amount of effort (i.e. proving Morley's theorem would be the same level of difficulty).

Also are there examples of nice categorizations? For example (this may be false but something in the spirit of) "omega-stable countable groups have a nice classification as products of some class of groups".

To sum up, I'm looking for "simple" applications that follow from basic results in, say Marker's text on Model Theory for example.

Comment: Second, one could prove that $\mathrm{ACF}_0$ is uncountably categorical by proving it's strongly minimal and the using the abstract theory of strongly minimal sets, thus avoiding Morley's theorem. But this is overkill, since you can give an easy purely algebraic proof of this fact using transcendence bases.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Yep. That was sort of the point. I was hoping for example where this wasn't overkill :)

Comment: The infinite version of Ramsey's Theorem follows from the finite version via compactness.

Comment: @vhspdfg: Thanks! The infinite version by itself is not too hard to prove though. I was hoping for a result you could point to and say: "Hey, that's much easier than the other known proofs"

Comment: What about the simple consequence of the elimination of quantifiers for the fields $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$: the projection of a semi-algebraic set is again semi-algebraic. (In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, this is called the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem.)

Comment: Moreover, there is an easy generalization of the four color theorem to infinite graphs which uses the theorem for the finite case and compactness.

Comment: @russoo: Would you care to elaborate more? Maybe even make this in to an answer?

Comment: @dav11 Exercise. Consider an infinite planar graph and an appropriate language and theory such that, if that graph did not admit a four-coloring, then by compactness there would be some finite subset of the theory (which we arrange to correspond to a finite subset of the graph) which does not admit a four-coloring.

Comment: It occurs that we can show the uniqueness of a countable atomless Boolean algebra by $\omega$-categoricity if we wished to avoid back-and-forth.

We can also show the existence of an algebraic closure of a field by compactness.

Comment: You can prove Steinitz's theorem on the existence of an algebraic closure through an easy compactness argument.

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Easy Applications of Model Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/248143)